# Detect when user loses access to Google account used for Google Sign-In

Tags: google-api

In our service, we offer Google Sign-In alongside email/password sign in, and need to know when a user loses access to their Google account so we can disable an integration.
Without forcing the user to re-authenticate with Google Sign-In, how can we detect when they lose access to their connected Google account?

The approach that I am thinking through my search is

1. obtain `access_token` and `refresh_token` through OAuth 2.0 authentication when user signs in on our service with Google Sign-In, save them in our database
2. periodically, make request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo` using saved `access_token` (we will get an error if user's google account is closed)
3. if `access_token` is expired, retrieve another one using `refresh_token`, then re-try step 2

Is this the right approach or is there a better way to achieve what we want?

Answer (score 0):

Google OAuth 2.0 Tokens expire in 3,600 seconds. They are valid until they are revoked or expired.

When you request the access token, make note of the expiration time in your database and consider the token valid until expiration.

The other option is to continue validating the access token on every request which takes more time than it is usually worth.

Google does not have a callback mechanism to notify you of expiration or revoking of a token.